# Активация пользователя Djoser

Tags: post, auth, django-rest-framework

Я использую Django Rest Framework и Djoser для регистрации и авторизации. Чтобы активировать пользователя, мне нужно отправить uid и token пользователя в POST-запросе. Когда я указываю все необходимое, то получаю ошибку о том, что пользователя с данным uid не существует. Токен при это правильный. В поле uid я вписываю обычное id пользователя.

Response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "detail": "Invalid user id or user doesn't exist.",
            "source": {
                "pointer": "/data/attributes/uid"
            },
            "status": "400"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В поле `uid` должно идти не обычное `id` пользователя, а именно `uid` - это первая часть ссылки из письма, которая идет перед токеном. Например для  URL вида https://example.com/#/activate/Ng/adhq76-779718994b36b3c95dd79d19ed0e90fb, токен - это **adhq76-779718994b36b3c95dd79d19ed0e90fb**, а `uid` - это **Ng**.